# How do I stop windows electron app from opening new window when notification is clicked?

Tags: windows, notifications, electron, electron-forge

I have an electronjs app running on windows. When I click on a windows Notification it always opens a new window for my app. How do I stop this and handle window creation myself?

My code, in the main process, looks like this:

```js
let notif = new Notification({
  title: ...
  body: ...
});

notif.on('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // Shouldn't this stop windows from opening a new window? 
  ... 
});

notif.show();
```

All of this works fine. The notification is shown, and the click handler is triggered. But then a new window is opened anyway.

The only other place I open new windows is on app "activate", but even if clicking the notification is activating the app this should never open a second window.

```js
app.on('activate', () => {
  if (app.isReady() && BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length == 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

Even stranger, this isn't happening when I test with `electron-forge start`, only after building with `@electron-forge/maker-appx` and distributing through the windows store.

Comment: @felipepastorelima I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using `process.platform` to separate mac and pc notification handling. Then manually setting the `toastXml` like this on pc.

This seems to work, and doesn't open a new window on click.

```
let notif = new Notification({
  silent: true,
  toastXml: `
    <toast activationType="protocol" launch="myapp://app/${route}">
      <visual>
        <binding template="ToastGeneric">
          <text>${title}</text>
          <text>${body}</text>
        </binding>
      </visual>
    </toast>`
});
notif.show();
```